# set browser headers for Chrome in Intent

Tags: android, google-chrome

my app uses the standard ACTION_VIEW intent to launch urls in the user's default browser. I would like to also set a http header, specifically the Referer header. I see the built in browser allows you to set the Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS extra on the intent. Chrome doesn't seem to support this extra and setting the Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER or Intent.EXTRA_ORIGINATING_URI also don't seem to set the Referer header. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a known limitation.  I have raised this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179325

Comment: I cannot view this issue, supposedly due to insufficient rights. Any updates on this?